Class of kids see the sun coming out for the first time
I don't remember if this is a short or a feature film. I saw it about 30+ years ago.
Details - It's raining all the time, A class of kids is in some shelter, and there is also an adult (teacher?)  there teaching them.
One of the kids, keep talking about how it once was, when the sun was out, flowers bloom, and it was green. All the kids laugh and ignore her. She also has some kind of a small refuge, where she has a picture of the sun ( i think).
There is some thought, that the sun is about to come out, and at a known time. And only the girl believes that.
At one point, the kids close the girl in some small room within the shelter. At that same moment (what else) the rain cease, and the sun is coming out.
All the kids, and the teacher, immediately look and go out of the shelter and into the sun.
They all collect flowers and enjoy the hot sun. (while the girl is still in the closet, shouting, calling for help)
After a while, the sun is again, gone, and the rain continues. When the kids return to the shelter, they are remembered of the girl, and free her from the closet. She goes outside, to find the rain again.

You're looking for All Summer in a Day, a short movie that aired on the PBS anthology show WonderWorks in 1982 and is based on a Ray Bradbury story of the same name. Here's its synopsis:

The story is about a class of schoolchildren on Venus, which in this story is a world of constant rainstorms, where the Sun is only visible for one hour every seven years.
One of the children, Margot, moved to Venus from Earth five years earlier, and she is the only one in her class to remember sunshine, since the Sun shone regularly on Earth. She describes the Sun as "a penny", or "like a fire in the stove", and the other children, being too young ever to have seen it themselves, refuse to believe her account of it. She is bullied and ostracized by the other students and is locked in a closet.

The movie is available on Youtube. Here's a clip:



